How can I precompile header only libraries using cmake?
My project is a game engine, and it currently looks something like this:
/build
/engine
    /include
        /engine.h
    /src
        /enginepch.h
        ...
    /vendor
        /header_only
            /include
                /header1.h
                ...
        /need_to_compile
        ...
    CMakeLists.txt
/testbed
    /stuffForTestingEngine
    CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt

My includePath has engine/vendor/** and engine/src/** and I'm doing all my coding in VSCode with the C/C++ ms-vscode extension.
./engine/CMakeLists.txt is as such:
project(engine)

# config "need_to_compile

# ...and I configured everything that needed compilation here: glm, glad, openal, libpng and glfw.

# linking

add_library(engine SHARED
    src/core/application.cpp
    src/core/engine.cpp
    # etc. These are all my source files.
)
add_library(engine::engine ALIAS engine)

target_include_directories(engine PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
target_include_directories(engine PRIVATE
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor
)
target_precompile_headers(engine PRIVATE src/enginepch.h)

target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC 
    glfw 
    png 
    openal
    glad
    glm::glm
) 

This setup and pch.h file worked great with all the std stuff, such as <chrono> and <string>.
As soon as I tried including any header_only lib in my pch file, it broke. For example:
# This works!
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

# This didn't.
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

The above setup generated the following error:
/engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog.h:12:10: fatal error: 'spdlog/common.h' file not found
A setup like #include <spdlog.h> failed with a similar error:
/engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog.h:12:10: fatal error: 'spdlog.h' file not found
To reproduce, copy my directory structure and create a CMake project, then try to pre-compile headers with target_precompile_headers(project PRIVATE src/pch.h)
# \project
#     \include
#     \src
#         \core\app.cpp
#         pch.h
#     \vendor
#         \header_only
#             \include
#                 header_file.h


CMakeLists.txt
project(project)


add_library(project SHARED
    src/core/app.cpp
)
add_library(project::project ALIAS project)

target_include_directories(project PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
target_include_directories(project PRIVATE
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor
)
target_precompile_headers(project PRIVATE src/cph.h)


pch.h
#include <header_file.h>

I tried many other variations of the #include statement, such as "lib", "lib.h", "lib/lib.h", , <lib/lib.h> and <lib.h>. None worked.
I tried including these header_only libs in CMakeLists, either by linking to an alias or adding a include_directory, but that didn't work.
I suspect that my setup is wrong, or that I have a fatal misunderstanding of what CMake/the compiler is doing.

Too much unrelated code, and at the same time not enough info to reproduce. But in general, when you have header-only library, make an interface library target: add_library(HeaderOnlyLib1 INTERFACE), target_include_directories(HeaderOnlyLib1 INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/whatever/include. and then just link other targets with it.

Tried this, error changed but still not working. Added those lines to my CMakeLists.txt, then called target_link_libraries(engine ...) with the newly added libraries. On my pch file, changed my include statement to #include "library.h"
Now, I get a problem specifically with spdlog. /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog.h:12:10: fatal error: 'spdlog/common.h' file not found.
spdlog uses <> notation, and common.h is in the same dir as spdlog.h

".. common.h is in the same dir as spdlog.h" - Such files hierarchy won't work for #include <sdplog/common.h>. This include directive implies that file common.h is located in the subdirectory named spdlog.

/engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog.h should probably be moved to /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog/spdlog.h and the /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/ should be an include directory added so that sdplog/common.h can be found since its a relative path to /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/

"As soon as I tried including any header_only lib in my pch file, it broke." - You expect that everyone knows what "broke" means in your case. But your problem is actually not clear with the details you provide. Please, add to your question post a [mcve], which would include the code (C, CMakeLists.txt) of your attempt and the complete error message you got with that attempt. For files noted in the error message should their place in your files hierarchy.

Moving /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/* to /engine/vendor/spdlog/include/spdlog/* worked! Thanks @drescherjm . As for the feedback regarding the question, I'll update it ASAP to make it clearer. Wasn't sure what I was thinking when I didn't include the errors themselves.

Side note: In my humble experience, precompiled headers are more trouble than they are worth in the long run. Sure, they speed up builds, but something always ends up going wrong; be it build failures, runtime errors due to things not having been recompiled or something else.. personally I just avoid them - have been burned too many times.
